# Compile C++ Code to behave the same in Windows and Linux

Tags: c++, linux, windows, g++, cygwin

I've installed cygwin and use it to program C++ on Windows.

I prefer to write my code (these are assignments) in Windows but the code also needs to be able to run on Linux. While the code ports well most of the time it appears that there are some things that work on Windows but cause segfaults on Linux (such as referencing uninitialized variables and pointers).

I compile using g++ in both Windows (via C:\cygwin\bin\g++.exe) and Linux, I don't understand why code that works in the former fails in the latter (or why they don't simply behave the same). How do I get my code to behave exactly the same in both? Is this even possible?

I am not using any windows specific libs though I am a C++ noob so I may be misunderstanding something simple/important. Lastly I know using uninitialized variables and pointers is bad - I'd like to their use cause segmentation faults in Windows.

Comment: Undefined behavior most likely - you're doing something wrong on both, but it only crashes on one. If you wrote correct code, it should work. Post the exact code that crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing with "referencing uninitialized variables and pointers" is called undefined behaviour. It means that "your luck may vary" - it may do something in one way on one system, and something else on a different system. Unfortunately, as part of "C and C++ are supposed to be efficient languages", the behaviour of undefined behaviour is just that - the compiler doesn't need to care for it, and there is nothing in the C or C++ standard that defines what is supposed to happen.

If you apply `-Wall` to your compiler, it should give you warnings for almost all types of uninitialized variables.

Make it your rule that whenever you declare a variable, you also assign it a value. It's never a bad idea to do this. Even if it's just assigning it some useless value, it's better than trying to identify why your calculation goes wrong somewhere deep inside a four-level nested loop.

You can also try using the Microsoft Visual Studio tools - there is a free "Express Edition" of these tools. If you compile with debug mode, it will generate extra code to (attempt to) detect use of uninitialized variables.

I'm not aware of a "library" that allows you to fault on uninitialized variables.

Comment: thanks for the explanation on undefined behavior. also, adding `-Wall` gave me a nice (long) list of everything I had not initialized and coming from Java this going to help.

Comment: Just to add to this: using `-ansi` and `-pedantic` help with portability too.

Answer (score 1):

> such as referencing uninitialized variables and pointers

Exactly. From my experience I have seen that C++ code compiled on Windows (with `Visual C++` or `MinGW GCC`) pointers are not initialized to NULL.

So something like this will not segfault. (You are not getting what you wanted but atleast you don't know it. Cruel. )

```
int *p;
*p = 1;
std::cout<<*p;
```

However on Linux systems (GCC) at least seems to initialize them to NULL. So the above code will segfault.

The best solution is to turn on your un-initialized variable warnings (gcc `Wuninitialized`) for the compiler you are using and then tell it to treat all warnings as errors (gcc `Werror`).

You can do this at least before trying to port the code.

For an even better analysis you can use tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).